# "Exercise" but not "exercize"

Tags: american-english, orthography, british-english, suffixes, ise-ize

Many words are spelled with *-ise* in British English and *-ize* in American English:

- *realise/realize*
- *sanitise/sanitize*
- *scrutinise/scrutinize*

But *exercise* can only be spelled with *-ise*, never with *-ize*.

Is there a good reason for this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Those are not the same kind of word. Your mistake is thinking that English spelling has something to do with its pronunciation, and this is in error.  It’s all about the etymology.  Consider also:

> abscise, advertise, advise, affranchise, apprise, arise, chastise,
>   circumcise, comprise, compromise, despise, devise, enterprise, exercise,
>   expertise, franchise, frise, galliardise, incise, merchandise, revise,
>   sunrise, supercise, supervise, televise.

And contrast that set with this set:

> analyse, autolyse, breathalyse, catalyse, chemolyse, dialyse, glycolyse,
>   haemolyse, heliochryse, histolyse, hydrolyse, lyse, metanalyse, paralyse,
>   photocatalyse, photolyse, plasmolyse, proteolyse, pryse, psychoanalyse.

It’s the etymology that counts, not the pronunciation. It turns out that [the *-ize* ending](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/100447) of words comes, per the OED, from:

> Cognate with French *-ise-r*, Italian *-izare*, Spanish *-izar*, < late Latin *-izāre, -īzāre,* < Greek *-ίζειν*, formative of verbs.

Whereas [*exercise*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/66088) has a wholly different provenance:

> Middle English *exercise*, < Old French *exercice* = Provençal *exercici*, *exercisi*  < Latin *exercitium*, < *exercēre*  to keep at work, busy, employ, practise, train (compare **exercise** *v.*), < *ex-*  (see **ex-** *prefix*<sup>1</sup>) + *arcēre* to shut up, restrain.

The note at *-ize* is quite long:

> The Greek verbs were partly intrans., as *βαρβαρίζειν* to play the barbarian, act or speak as a barbarian, side with the barbarians, *τυραννίζειν* to side with the tyrants, partly transitive as *καθαρίζειν* to purify, clean, *θήσαυρίζειν* to treasure up. Those formed on national, sectarian, or personal names were primarily intransitive, as *Ἀττικίζειν* to Atticize in manners, to speak Attic, *Φιλιππίζειν* to act or speak for Philip, to philippize, *Ἑλληνίζειν* to ‘do’ the Greek, act as a Greek, speak Greek, Hellenize; also, to make Greek. A few words of this form connected with or used in early Christianity, were latinized already in the 3rd or 4th cent. by Christian writers: such were *βαπτίζειν baptizāre, εὐαγγελίζειν euangelizāre, κατηχίζειν catechizāre, σκανδαλίζειν scandalizāre, ἀναθηματίζειν anathēmatizāre, χριστιανίζειν christiānizāre, ἰουδαίζειν iūdaizāre.* Others continued to be formed both in ecclesiastical and philosophical use, e.g. *canōnizāre, dæmonizāre, syllogizāre* (Boethius Aristot. Anal.); and this became established as the normal form for the latinizing of Greek verbs, or the formation of verbs upon Greek analogies. In medieval Latin and the modern languages these have been formed also on Latin or modern national names, and the use has been extended to the formation of verbs from Latin adjectives or ns. This practice probably began first in French; in modern French the suffix has become *-iser*, alike in words from Greek, as *baptiser, évangéliser, organiser*, and those formed after them from Latin, as *civiliser, cicatriser, humaniser*.
>
> **Hence, some have used the spelling *-ise* in English, as in French, for all these words, and some prefer *-ise* in words formed in French or English from Latin elements, retaining *-ize* for those formed < Greek elements.**
>
> But the suffix itself, whatever the element to which it is added, is in its origin the Greek *-ιζειν*, Latin *-izāre*; and, as the pronunciation is also with *z*, there is no reason why in English the special French spelling should be followed, in opposition to that which is at once etymological and phonetic. In this Dictionary the termination is uniformly written *-ize*. (In the Greek *-ιζ-*, the *i* was short, so originally in Latin, but the double consonant *z* (= *dz, ts*) made the syllable long; when the *z* became a simple consonant,  /-idz/  became *īz*, whence English  /-aɪz/.)

This is to be contrasted with [the *-ise* suffix](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/99942) from ***exercise***, of which the OED says:

> Suffix of ns., repr. Old French *-ise*, properly:—Latin -*ītia*, but also, in words of learned formation, put for Latin -*icia, -itia, -icium, -itium,* as in Latin *justitia, judicium, servitium*, Old French *justise, juise, servise*. Hence it became a living suffix, forming abstract nouns of quality, state, or *function, as in couard-ise, friand-ise, gaillard-ise, marchand-ise*. In the words from Latin, -*ise* was subsequently changed in French to -*ice*, as in justice, service, in which form the suffix mostly appears in English, as in *justice, service, cowardice*; but -*ise* is found in *franchise, merchandise*, the obsolete or archaic *niggardise, quaintise, riotise, truandise, valiantise, warrantise*, and in such barely-naturalized words as *galliardise, gourmandise, paliardise*; **also, in *exercise*, French *exercice*, Latin *exercitium*.** Native formations on the same type are *inconvenientise, sluggardise.*

So you see, the spelling is all about the etymology, not about the pronunciation.

Comment: No, it's not _all_ about the etymology. The _z_ in _analyze_ has no etymological justification.

Comment: @ColinFine Where did I write *analyze*? :)

Comment: You didn't. I did. It is a notorious example where AmE prefers _z_ _despite_ the etymology.

Comment: @ColinFine I know, I was teasing. I myself don't like *-yze* and so do not use it. I analyse things; I don't *analyze them.  The result is therefore an analysis, not an *analyzis.

Comment: @tchrist; or teazing. (See Austen, J., _passim_)

Comment: @tchrist I prefer z. All words listed make the zzzzzzzz sound not ssssssssss.

Comment: Rezistants is fewtyle. We are outnumbered by Amearicanz!

Comment: "Your mistake is thinking that English" has any truck with logic.  (Which, to various degrees, applies to all _living_ languages of course)